# What should be ideal date on calendar icon?

Tags: usability, icons, dates, calendar, numbers

I am designing a calendar icon for an app, I am putting a random date right now on it, what should be ideal date that I should put. Is there any usability research done on the same?
I know the best scenario can be if it can display the current date, but right now it might be too much an overkill to develop such a feature, so what should be the ideal date that i should put on the icon? Blackberry puts it to be 31, another number which I though was quite eye catchy was 23. Is there any such paradigm that a particular date is catchier?

Comment: you might be over-thinking this.

Comment: My favorite icon set uses `31`: http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/search/fugue/#keyword=calendar Another option is to just make it a generic calendar with no dates, like some of the other icons in there.

Comment: What is the app doing? Pretty key information for giving a reasonable answer :)

Comment: Agree with @DA01 if I'm honest. I think it's only pedants who would notice and we all work in UX already!

Comment: 17 is the best.

Comment: The ideal number is obviously 42 :)

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky this is funny because 42 isn't on a calendar!! You are such a joker :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing a google search on *calendar icon* and then you capture the results (if worth it). Just by skimming the results I saw that 9 was a popular number, but not far from others.

From the [Semiotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics) perspective 31 might work, as people easily identify it as the maximum number of days a month can get, and design-wise is filling.

I think that only having the red bar at the top and a big bold black number (or calendar grid (SMTWXFS) id size permits) at the bottom is good enough for people to identify the icon.

**MORE ON ICONS:** I bumped today into this link: [Tips for Designing Great Icons and Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) from the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556). Worth having a look for people that want to design their own icons.

Comment: I like the idea of using 31 to help users grok the number's meaning.

Comment: I'd had assumed that that that would have been the most popular number in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

If it is technically feasible, update the icon on an hourly/daily base to show the current date/day. This way, the user sees the current date/day by just browsing through the set of application icons without starting the calendar application.

Technically, it may require configuring and running a system service to redraw the icon at midnight without user interaction.

Comment: That would be the preferred route (as per iOS) but as the OP mentions in the question *"but right now it might be too much an overkill to develop such a feature"*